# how to call an intent with my swipe buttons

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, swipe

Here I have a code where you can swipe the tab menus, but I want that after a swipe another activity is opened, for example Simmering.class.
I think this should go with an intent, but how or where should I put it.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code in onCreateView method of your fragment class. check for the position after which you want to start new activity. And in it call the startActivity method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Simmering.class);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can you please go in further detail? where do i put this code exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know, that starting new activity after swipe hide page you're swiping to? If your answer is yes, you can use `ViewPager`'s [onPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html). It's methods are invoked when page is changed/updated etc. Usage is following:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i already found an option to achieve what i wanted, here is the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // action with ID action_refresh was selected
    case R.id.action_refresh:
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.refresh_clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    // action with ID action_settings was selected
    case R.id.action_settings:
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.settings_clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
    return true;
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment=null;

        switch(i){
        case 0: fragment = new Home(); break;
        case 1: fragment = new Simmering(); break;
        case 2: fragment = new LugnerCity(); break;
        case 3: fragment = new Gmunden(); break;
        case 4: fragment = new Salzburg(); break;
        case 5: fragment = new Linz(); break;
        case 6: fragment = new Saalbach(); break;
        case 7: fragment = new Innsbruck(); break;
        case 8: fragment = new Reutte(); break;
        case 9: fragment = new Bregenz(); break;
        case 10: fragment = new Kufstein(); break;
        case 11: fragment = new Bratislava(); break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 12;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch(position) {
        case 0: return "Home";
        case 1: return "Simmering";
        case 2: return "Lugner City";
        case 3: return "Gmunden";
        case 4: return "Salzburg"; 
        case 5: return "Linz"; 
        case 6: return "Saalbach"; 
        case 7: return "Innsbruck";
        case 8: return "Reutte";
        case 9: return "Bregenz";
        case 10: return "Kufstein";
        case 11: return "Bratislava";
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```